# Get only the value out of parsed JSON in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js

Hello I am a newbie to JS and Node, I am making an application that should return the NodeJS version and V8 Version using `process.versions()`, but this will return a JSON formatted-output, but I only need the value of `v8` and `node`, so how can I do this?

Comment: [`process.versions`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#processversion) (not a function btw) returns an object. So `process.versions.node` etc will work.

Comment: Here the documentation on versions in [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/docs/v0.10.12/api/process.html#process_process_version)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

```
const {node ,v8}=process.versions
console.log(node);
console.log(v8);
```

See [repl](https://replit.com/join/kqhmnbsscw-shubhamdixit863)